# How to extract single item from IChangeSet?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Often I need to filter my observable connection and get a single item from it in similar fashion the `FirstOrDefault` does on `IEnumerable`. This is super useful for `SelectedItem` property. How to do it in reactive UI?

Example code:

```
IObservabel<T> = _mySourceList
.Connect()
.Top(1)
.?()
```

There are functions `Maximum` and `Minimum` but they only work on concrete types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ToCollection()`](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/dynamicdata/observablelistex/d5582799) to convert the `IObservable<IChangeSet>` to a `IObservable<IReadOnlyCollection>`. From there it's a simple `First()` call (or whatever you need) to get the first element of the list. See the following example:

```
SourceList<int> list = new SourceList<int>();
IObservable<int?> observeFirst = list.Connect()
    .ToCollection()
    .Select(it => it.Any()
        ? (int?)it.First()
        : null);
        
IDisposable disposable = observeFirst.Subscribe(it => {
    Console.WriteLine("The 'first' element is: "+it);
});

Console.WriteLine("Start");

list.Add(4);
list.Add(9);
list.RemoveAt(0);
list.Insert(0, 12);
list.Insert(1, 20);
list.Insert(0, 50);
list.RemoveAt(0);
list.Clear();

disposable.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine("End");
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Start
The 'first' element is: 4
The 'first' element is: 4
The 'first' element is: 9
The 'first' element is: 12
The 'first' element is: 12
The 'first' element is: 50
The 'first' element is: 12
The 'first' element is: 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get the first item (or default) of the source list whenever there is a change, it would be:

```
IObservabel<T> = _mySourceList
.Connect()
.Select(_ => _mySourceList.Items.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: But `ElementAt(0)` will contain first change (`Change<T>`), where I want to have observable providing first item of _mySourceList.

Comment: As I said, I wasn't sure about your requirements. But the second part of my answer should provide the first element and pipe through the observable whenever there is a change. I will remove the first part of my answer.